# Quarkus 3.x - Azure Function - function.json

Tags: azure-functions, quarkus

We are using Quarkus version 3.1.2.Final for creating Azure Functions. Maven generates the function.json file but the section 'methods' does not contain a 'DELETE'. Only the following is present "methods" : [ "GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS" ].

Is there a reason why 'DELETE' is not included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have created an Azure functions using Quarkus version 3.1.2.Final to check the same:***

[image]
[image]

Opened the application in IntelliJ IDE to check the Http methods:

*I could see the **DELETE** in ***Http methods*** as shown below:*

[image]

***And `function.json` generated methods:***

[image]

Comment: I've tried to add an image but I'm not able to do this...

This is our API Endpoint:
`code`
@DELETE
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{id}")
pubic Response deleteItem(@PathParam("id") final Long id) {...}

This setup doesn't generate a DELETE method in the generated function.json file

Comment: ***`API`:***

![API](https://i.imgur.com/ky4KRSc.png)

***`function.json`:***

![function.json](https://i.imgur.com/P49bc9K.png)

Comment: If possible, can you provide your code excluding the sensitive information. So that it will be easy to check.

Comment: I've stripped it down to it's bare essentials and I get the same result when I ran: mvn clean package azure-functions:package

Where can I send a zip of the code to?

Comment: Can you try `mvn clean install` once?

Comment: Same result... only this is generated "methods" : [ "GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS" ],

Comment: you can push your code to [github](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-push-an-existing-project-to-github) if you have an account and provide me the link of your repository.

Comment: OK... I think you have access to https://github.com/DominiqueClaes/aaa

Comment: @user965220, Can you check if this [code](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/Quarkus-Azurefunction) help to achieve your requirement?

Comment: That solution adds the method 'DELETE' to the file 'function.json'. It does ignore all other HTTP methods. Now only 'GET' and 'DELETE' are added to the file. But why is my initial code not working? It only misses the 'DELETE' method and all others are recognized...

Comment: @user965220, There was function code missing in the code you provided. I have added the AssessmentEndpoint and DeleteAssessmentResponse [classes](https://i.imgur.com/8MZKMK2.png) to my default generated quarkus function code with required [Http methods](https://i.imgur.com/JnhyGbZ.png).

Comment: I understand, but previously we didn't need the Function class. This issue arises since we implemented the Quarkus upgrade

Comment: As far I understand, that might be happening with the latest version.

Comment: Than it must be an issue with Quarkus...

Comment: Or do you suspect something else?

Comment: I feel it could be issue with Quarkus latest version. Was it generating DELETE method without function code in previous versions when you tried?

Comment: Previously we would define our own function.json and in combination with the previous Quarkus version and several Maven plugins, an Azure Function package was created. With the new Quarkus version, a function.json was not needed to create and we could remove several plugins which make our code much cleaner.